# What are Apple's autofill field names?

Tags: html, accessibility, osx-mavericks

Now that Mavericks is out, and it can use autofill to handle credit card info, are there specific field names they look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure exactly about how Mavericks handles it but in chrome you can accomplish autofill in a way like this:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
    <input name="cc-name" autocomplete="cc-name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required />
    <input name="cc-number" autocomplete="cc-number" type="text" placeholder="Credit Card Number" required />
    <input name="cc-exp" autocomplete="cc-exp" type="text" placeholder="Expire Date" required />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send my personal info to this person.." />
</form>
```

If safari works how chrome does it might have a regex scanner that looks for familiar terms and fills it in to the best of it's ability. It's very difficult to find any full details on how properly write an autocomplete form. The best bet is try it out and see what works then update your post with your results.

From my research it seems that for an autocomplete form to be filled with credit card info the web page MUST be under a secure domain ( https:// )

This is a list of all the autofill values that might work http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofill-field

*Good luck! and don't abuse it.. That being said, not too many people will actually have their credit card set up for autofill for security reasons. I personally wouldn't for the risk of someone abusing the autofill feature and stealing my information with malicious JavaScript.*